# Class for drop down views similar to passbook

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Are there any classes which could be used to make a drop down view similar to passbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the Apple class library - No. Somebody might have written something open source that has similar features, but you're unlikely to find that through Stack Overflow. Try searching Github.